# Поиск кратчайшего пути в графе на SQL

Tags: sql, алгоритм, postgresql

Пишу SQL -код для поиска кратчайшего пути(От 'S' в 'Y'), остановился на подсчёте суммарной стоимости

```
with recursive  temp AS
(select id, array[id] as path,weight as price,
        false as cycle
    from "DbWorkHierarchy"
    where id ='S'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "DbWorkHierarchy".id, temp.path || "DbWorkHierarchy".id as path,
           "DbWorkHierarchy".id= any(temp.path) as cycle,
             temp.price + "DbWorkHierarchy".weight as price
    from "DbWorkHierarchy" JOIN temp on(temp.id ="DbWorkHierarchy".par_id) AND NOT cycle )
SELECT id,path,price from temp;
```

Получаю вот такую ошибку:

> [2020-11-20 16:20:04] [42804] ОШИБКА: в конструкции UNION нельзя обобщить типы integer и boolean
> [2020-11-20 16:20:04] Позиция: 276

Вот таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так? Притом, если не считать суммарный вес(price), всё работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примечание: Граф ориентирован, направление от par_id к id

Comment: вы `UNION ALL` чего с чем делаете? Похоже у вас в запросе все перемешалось.

Comment: Вы порядок полей в подзапросах проверьте, да...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо пользователям  tym32167,Akina. Я действительно неправильно указал порядок полей в подзапросах.
Итого решение такое :

```
with recursive  temp AS
(select id, array[id] as path,0 as price,
        false as cycle
    from "DbWorkHierarchy"
    where id ='S'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "DbWorkHierarchy".id, temp.path || "DbWorkHierarchy".id as path,
           temp.price + "DbWorkHierarchy".weight as price,
           "DbWorkHierarchy".id= any(temp.path) as cycle

    from "DbWorkHierarchy" JOIN temp on(temp.id ="DbWorkHierarchy".par_id) AND NOT cycle )
SELECT id,path,price from temp where id = 'Y' and price in (select min(price) from temp where id='Y');
```